# php sybase install on mac

Tags: php, module, sybase

I have installed the entire lamp stack with homebrew on my macbook pro.  I am in need of getting the sybase module installed but am having the worst time trying to figure it out.  I have done upteen google searches and read over the php.net section on sybase:

> http://php.net/manual/en/sybase.installation.php

I have no clue when it says:

> To enable Sybase-CT support configure PHP --with-sybase-ct[=DIR]

I was hoping to reach out to someone who has enabled/installed this on a mac or unix environment.  Hope you can let me know the steps I need to run to get this up and running so I can use:

`sybase_connect();`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP is configured in php.ini, so look for something like ```;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll``` (DLL only used on Windows) and this: flag in php.ini: ```[Sybase-CT]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use FreeTDS to connect to Sybase from your Mac's PHP. Will be much easier than trying to configure the Sybase-CT library.

Comment: I went over to the FreeTDS website and will download their package.  Do you happen to know or maybe walk me through the steps on integrating it with PHP?  Know of some website tutorials?

Comment: This was the answer.  I got FreeTDS installed on my mac and then used homebrew to install what I needed

brew install php55-pdo-dblib

Worked like a charm.  Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

That section is asking for where on your system the Sybase installation is.  To connect to a Sybase DB, you need to have either the client piece, SDK, or server piece installed on the local system.

The Sybase home directory includes the connection libraries that PHP is looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to connect up to a sybase database via a mac?

Comment: Yes, but you need to either install the database on the mac, or install the SDK on the mac.  You will need the Sybase connection binaries on your system in some way.

Comment: Ok, I will see what I can find.  Thanks for the response.  Appreciate it.